# Sending linux commands over serial

Tags: android, linux, shell, serial-port

this is my first post, I have a question about being able to send linux commands over a serial connection to an android device. I have heard of putty and tried to use it, but i am ultimately lost with it. Like if I was in the linux shell of the android and could type, "reboot" and the device would reboot. The android device has a virtual serial connection, and I have been able to connect to it using putty, but I don't know where to go after that.
I know this is confusing and may be completely wrong, thank you for your time in advance

Comment: Try ask this question on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Please download Android SDK and use adb.exe to acquire linux shell on the device and then you can do many things.

Serial ports are for different uses dont try to use them unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: but i cant use adb because the phone wont boot up fully, and adb setting is off.